# Single DirectX/C++ project for both WinAPI and WinRT

Tags: c++, winapi, windows-runtime, directx, game-engine

Currently I'm working on a simple game engine project. I would like it to be independent from the platform, so for started I've taken only classical Windows Desktop application and Metro Style app.

From this picture:
[Windows APIs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3XNPL.png)

We can see that the C/C++ blocks are common for both parts. In other words, I would like to easily switch between platform configurations. I've created simple WinAPI static library that you can easily include in the project, as well as DirectX game-engine and it works perfectly. However, I'm having issues to do the same with WinRT (used in Metro Style apps).

Is it possible to have one Visual Studio project that can use WinAPI or WinRT? It would be perfect if I could have like one single entry point for a game and just switch underlying APIs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. A single VS project that either generates a classic win32 exe and a WinRT (nowadays Universal) applications is not possible.

In theory they could have made it possible, like you can have a single project that generates a console application or gui application. The difference between the two boils down to one (or two) flags.

The difference between a classic exe and a WinRT app is quite big: There are manifests and packaging and special sauce signing not to mention the resources (icons, etc) are specified differently.

In the Visual studio UI this is manifested by a different set of property pages, besides the common core of compiler + linker ones of course.

The other reason is one of strategy. Microsoft wants you to move forward and embrace the WinRT API. That is the API set that works across all Windows devices  (if you ignore the Win7 elephant in the room). Supporting a dual mode will send the wrong signal to developers.

As a side note that the very windows headers (windows.h) are annotated by API family. `CreateNamedPipe` is `#ifdef` out in a WinRT application, or for example there is `CreateFile` for classic apps and `CreateFile2` for modern apps.

Comment: A single vcxproj containing both a UWP and a classic Windows desktop app is in theory possible with a lot of custom ``.props`` files, but generally a huge pain and fragile. It's better to have parallel vcxproj files for each type, with the code shared. I use this technique for DirectXTK, DirectXTex, DirectXMesh. As for how to make the code build in all these contexts, see [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2012/09/17/dual-use-coding-techniques-for-games.aspx), but keep in mind that the 'appmodel' is quite different so sharing utility code is good, sharing UI is not.